Simplicial Subcomplex vs. Linear Embedding
I am a little lost with the definitions of simplicial subcomplexes and linear embeddings, and how they compare to each other. More precisely, I do not understand why the following theorems are not contradictory.
Brehm and Sarkaria showed that for every $d\geq 2$, and $k$ with $d+1\leq k\leq 2d$, there is a finite $d$-dimensional simplicial complex $X$ which admits a piecewise linear embedding in $\mathbb{R}^k$ but not a geometric/linear embedding, see also this answer.
Adiprasito and Patakov showed the following "Kind-of Fary's theorem":
Consider $X$ a finite simplicial complex and a PL embedding $\phi:X\to M$, where $M$ is a PL-manifold. Then there is a triangulation $M'$ of $M$ that contains $X$ as a subcomplex.
Since $M := \mathbb{R}^k$ is a PL-manifold, this theorem implies that any PL embedding of $X$ into $\mathbb{R}^k$ yields a triangulation of $\mathbb{R}^k$ containing $X$ as a subcomplex.
Together with the first theorem, this means that there exist simplicial complexes that are subcomplexes of a triangulation of $\mathbb{R}^k$ but do not embed linearly into $\mathbb{R}^k$.
My question is: What does it mean that a triangulation of $\mathbb{R}^k$ contains $X$ as a subcomplex? Or, how can it be that $X$ being a subcomplex does not give rise to a linear embedding of $X$ in $\mathbb{R}^k$?


A triangulation of a topological space $Z$ is a pair $(W,f)$ consisting of a simplicial complex $W$ and a homeomorphism $f: |W|\to Z$, where $|W|$ is the geometric realization of $W$ (the topological space underlying $W$). In particular, a triangulation of $\mathbb R^k$ need not be linear in the sense that images under $f$ of simplices in $W$ need not be affine simplices.

One says that a triangulation $(W, f: |W|\to Z)$ contains a simplicial complex $X$ as a subcomplex if $X$ is isomorphic to a subcomplex of $W$. (There is a bit of an abuse of the notation here, but you will get used to it once you get more comfortable with the subject.) In particular, if $Z=\mathbb R^k$, one does not necessarily get an affine embedding of $X$ in $\mathbb R^k$ (meaning a topological embedding $|X|\to \mathbb R^k$ which is affine on every simplex).



Thank you for your response. I’m curious where in Adiprasito’s proof this becomes apparent, as it begins with a linear embedding of a refinement $\tilde{X}$ of $X$. I suspect my (incorrect) intuition of geometric simplices holds until they apply 'edge subdivisions' and 'valid edge contractions' to transform $\tilde{X}$ into $X$. Do you happen to know if a valid edge contraction can make a geometric simplicial complex non-geometric? In other words, are there simplicial complexes that can be linearly embedded before, but not after, this operation?

@Leo: such complexes exist but getting a specific example would require more work than I have time for. You can ask an MO question if you are interested.
